# authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode not working with latest System.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, azure-active-directory

I used the below code for azure active directory authentication. it fails at authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode stating that this method does not exist. when I tried to verify it shows that in version 3.1 dll. There is authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync method. I am unable to modify this code to make it async as it is on startup. Any suggestions on this to convert to async

```
 public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           ConfigureAuth(app);
        }
    }


public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        //If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                            code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);

                            return Task.FromResult(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
```

Comment: I think checking out the [ADAL .NET Ref Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/active-directory/adal/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory) may prove useful!

Answer (score 3):

There were a number of breaking changes from ADAL v2 to ADAL v3. Probably your quickest solution here would be to simply use the older version of ADAL, which you can download from Nuget [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.28.3).

Otherwise, you can look at our existing samples which have migrated to ADAL v3 [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/60e5685dc72a6199f683ce6d2f0d8ed2263357c2/WebAppGraphAPI/Utils/AuthenticationHelper.cs).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can use old version but I am also using graphapi from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console which uses latest version with all async methods. any suggestion please.

Comment: Not exactly sure i understand your question here. If you are using a sample, which uses adal v3, then simply use the sample code to authenticate. I do not recommend trying to mix and mash code from different versions of ADAL.

Comment: Is there a reason that VS2017 Update 3 doesn't support v3 out of the box?  This is maddening when trying to setup and new project with the latest and greatest.